# Get All Colum names where its value equals 1 on a specific row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was just wondering whether there is a simple statement to get all columns of a row that equals a defined value.

I have a table which represent the rights a user has.

e.g.

```
userid | right A | right B | right C | right D
----------------------------------------------
    1  |     0   |     0   |    1    |    1
----------------------------------------------
    2  |     1   |     0   |    1    |    1
----------------------------------------------
    3  |     0   |     0   |    0    |    1
```

i need a query that returns me all colums of a user that has the value 1

for user 2 the result would look like

'right A', 'right C', 'right D'

at the moment i load the complete row and iterate over the result to get the column names but i would love to do this directly in my query.

According to MySQL a where clause in show columns etc. only tests the name, but not a value of a specific row.

A query to filter all values out of a result that are not 1 would also help, but i must work without knowing all the column names :-/

maybe a procedure is an option but thats just outsourceing the code from php to mysql :-/

Any ideas or complete impossible?

Thank in advance! :)

Comment: So the desired result is a single `varchar` for each row with a comma separated list of column-names?

Comment: actually it's a tinyint but i think this dosn't matter, as long as i get the column names that are fitting a value in a defined row

Comment: Yes, the type of the columns is `tinyint`, but you want to concat the column names.

Comment: ah sorry, misunderstood that. :) the best result would be an mysql resource that can be handled in php, but a varchar would also be great, besides i think that i have to explode ist and also have to iterate.

Comment: Why not simply normalize your data?

Comment: You may try to use **EAV** to create dynamic columns in your table..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, you mentioned that you are using `MySQL`, you can use `IF` on this

```
SELECT  CONCAT_WS(', ', IF(`right A` = 1, 'right A', NULL), 
                        IF(`right B` = 1, 'right B', NULL),
                        IF(`right C` = 1, 'right C', NULL),
                        IF(`right D` = 1, 'right D', NULL)) columnList
FROM    tableName
WHERE   userID = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68cbe/2)

Create a *dynamic sql* for 50 columns, example

```
SET @dbaseName = (SELECT DATABASE());  // FILL DATABASE NAME HERE
SET @tableName = 'TableName';          //      TableName
SET @userValue = 2;                    //      value of UserID

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('IF(`',COLUMN_NAME , '` = 1, ''',COLUMN_NAME,''', NULL)')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = @dbaseName AND
       COLUMN_NAME  LIKE 'right%';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT CONCAT_WS('', '',', @sql, ') AS ColumnList
                   FROM    tableName
                   WHERE   userid = ', @userValue);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99893/1)

Comment: Thanks! But as i mentioned it has to work without knowing all the column names. Besides there are more then 50 columns at the moment, my client wants total controll for everything.....also im just lazy :p

Comment: "Besides there are more then 50 columns at the moment" Uh-oh.

Comment: @Danack yep. its a big CMS, not my fault, i'm just the guy who has to handle this :(

Comment: @JW: omg!!! thank you really really much! I'm a little bit on time right now but i'll test it later this day. Never thought someone would came up with siomething like this :D

Comment: i accepted it, even when it's not working - which i don't think. just wow :)

Comment: it totally worked!!! Thanks again even when i have absolutely no idea what this code is doing. maybe time to visit my DB class again.....